# Fortran 95 Taylor series program unexpected behavior

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

Disclaimer: I am very new to fortran programming, so probably there will be quite a few mistakes in here.

The objective is to run the Taylor series for the sin(x) function: the degree of the polynomial and point in which it is to be evaluated (compared with the real sin(x)) are to be fed the program through the command pannel.

Then the program should compare the values of the sin(x) function and the polynomial at the point given and, if the difference between the two is bigger than a "tolerance" value given at the beginning, offer the user to either finish the program or enter a higher number of terms for the vector used to calculate the polynomial (thus increasing its degree and precision -suposedly-).

In any case, when the program ends it should write the results (sin(x) in the point given, value of the polynomial in that point and absolute value of their difference) in a taylor.dat file.

Problem is, it will compile and work properly, but if the degree entered is greater than 2 it will just do nothing after entering the data and exit the program. ¿Is there anything I can do to try and fix this?

Hope the bits in Spanish don´t make it incomprehensible (if it isn´t already)

```
program taylor

implicit none

integer :: ierr, n, i, j, k, b, z, y 
real*8 :: x, tol, a, ani, puntoE, taylorn, err
real*8, allocatable :: Vector(:)
open(unit=12,file='Taylor.dat',status='new',iostat=ierr)
print*, ierr
print*, 'DESARROLLO DE TAYLOR PARA LA FUNCION sen(x) CENTRADO EN 0'
    print*,
    10 print*, 'Introducir numero de terminos del vector usado para el 
    desarrollo'
    read*, N 
    z=N+(N-1)
    print*, 'El grado del desarrollo sera=', z
    print*, 
    print*, 'Introducir x'
    read*, x 
    print*, 'Introducir tolerancia'
    read*, tol

allocate(Vector(n))


do i= 1, N+(N-1)                                       
    a= (-1)**(i-1)                                     ! a = (-1)**(n)
    b= 1
    do j= 1, (2*(i-1)+1)
        b= b*j                                         ! b = (2*n+1)!
    end do 
    !print*, 'a=', a 
    !print*, 'b=', b
    ani= a/b                                           ! Término del vector 
    !print*, 'ani=', ani 
    Vector(i)=ani 
    !print*, 'vector=', Vector
end do 


puntoE=x

do k= 1, N
    taylorn=taylorn+puntoE*Vector(k)                   ! Valor del desarrollo
end do 
err= abs(sin(x)-taylorn)

deallocate(Vector)

print*, 'Valor del sen(x) en x=', sin(x)
print*, 'Valor del polinomio con grado',z,'en',x,'=',taylorn
print*, 'Error en la aproximacion=', err
print*,

if(err>tol)then 
    print*, 'La precision es menor que la especificada: introducir un mayor numero de terminos "N"'
    print*,
    print*, 'Para introducir un numero mayor de terminos, pulse 1'
    print*, 'Para finalizar el programa, pulse 2'
    read*, y 

if(y==1) then
  go to 10
  else
  stop
end if

end if 

write(12, *) 'Valor del sen(x) en x=' 
write(12, *) sin(x)
write(12, *)
write(12, *) 'Valor del polinomio con grado',z,'en',x,'=' 
write(12, *) taylorn
write(12, *)
write(12, *) 'Error en la aproximacion=' 
write(12, *) err

end program taylor
```

Comment: I surmise that `n` is the degree of the solution you seek.  The code allocates `vector` to length `n`.  In the first `do` loop the index (`i`) runs from `1` to `2n-1`, and a value is assigned to the `i`th element of `vector`.  When `n>=2` the code writes to elements of `vector` which don't exist (e.g. `vector(3)`).  It's one of the sometimes surprising features of Fortran that this error is not, by default, caught during execution.  Try recompiling your code with *array bounds checking* enabled, re-run, then fix.  I'm sure this is a duplicate of (many) other questions here on SO.

Comment: It is good to use some empty lines, but this is too much. The code then does not fit into the code window and we must scroll a lot to see it. You don't need an empty line after each code line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found your problem. You are modifying the array vector outside of its bounds for orders greater than 2. For example, I input a line printing the value of i and the size of the array 'vector' in the line immediately before the line assigning the value of ani to vector(i).

With this line "    print*, i, size(Vector)   " , I get:

```
       1           3
       2           3
       3           3
       4           3
       5           3
```

So at i>3 you assigning values to a non-existent location in Vector. Your code then throws a 'SIGABRT' error when I try to deallocate the array.

You must adjust the structure of this loop to only input values to Vectors bounds.